# How to I relate ManyToMany relationship in a single form with single submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have two models which have ManyToMany relationship, Category and Post.I am trying to incorporate two modelforms, post_form and category_form in a same form with one submit button. How do I show the relationship when I save it?

Currently, when I add same category_name for two different posts, it gives me warning saying it already exists. I would like to be able to choose the same category_name in dropdown or something similar. Please help. If this is not possible what are my alternatives?

```
Models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name       = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    category_slug       = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES      = (
                        ('draft', 'Draft'),
                        ('published', 'Published'),
                        )

    title               = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug                = models.SlugField(max_length=250, 
                                        unique_for_date='publish')
    body                = models.TextField()
    publish             = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                                        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                        default='draft')
    categories          = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('posts:post_detail',
            args=[self.publish.year,
                self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                self.slug])

Views.py

def post_list(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts/post_list.html', {'post_list': queryset})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug            = post,
                                   status          = 'published',
                                   publish__year   = year,
                                   publish__month  = month,
                                   publish__day    = day)
    return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', {'post':instance})

def post_create(request):
    post_form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    category_form = CategoryForm(request.POST or None)

    if post_form.is_valid() and category_form.is_valid():
    post_form_instance = post_form.save()
    category_form_instance = category_form.save()
    print (request.POST)
    print (post_form.is_valid)

    context = {'post_form':post_form, 'category_form':category_form}
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)

forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model   = Post
    fields  = [
            'title',
            'slug',
            'body',
            'publish',
            'status',
            ]


class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model   = Category
    fields  = [
            'category_name',
            'category_slug',                
            ]
post_form.html

<!--DOCTYPE html -->

<html>
    <head>
    </head>


    <body>
    <form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}

    <h1>Form</h1>


    {{ post_form.as_p }} 
    {{ category_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Create Post" />

    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to achieve and what exactly are you asking. As per your code, you are creating entries for categories and entries of posts. What you should be doing instead is making entries of posts, whilst providing option to select the categories associated to it. Please understand your situation, and your current code better.

Try this:

```
forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model   = Post
    fields  = [
            'title',
            'slug',
            'body',
            'publish',
            'status',
            'categories',
            ]
views.py
def post_create(request):
    post_form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if post_form.is_valid() and category_form.is_valid():
    post_form_instance = post_form.save()
    context = {'post_form':post_form,}
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)

post_form.html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>


    <body>
    <form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}

    <h1>Form</h1>


    {{ post_form.as_p }} 

    <input type="submit" value="Create Post" />

    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was exactly looking for what you asked me to try. Can you help and tell me how would I achieve adding NEW categories in the same form?